# Log in system with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, authentication

I'm trying to make a website where you can sign up and log in to the created account(s) I don't want to save the usernames and passwords to a database or anything (this is a school project) so that is not of importance, I just want to be able to save an account through local storage if that is possible and be able to log in so:

1: how do i create an account that can be saved through localstorage.

2: how do i make it log in if the username and password are correct, and do the opposite if they are incorrect

how do i do this in Jquery? thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div id="log-in-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" id="close-log-in">x</span>
        <p><label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username"></p>
        <p><label>Password</label><input type="password" id="password"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="submit">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sign-up-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" id="close-sign-up">x</span>
        <p><label>Username</label><input type="text" id="sign-username"></p>
        <p><label>Password</label><input type="password" id="sign-password"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

These are modals with username and password textfields, i open the modals by clicking a "Log In" button or "Sign Up" button on the website menu.

Comment: Have you tried any jQuery code mixed with adding/retrieving items from LocalStorage ?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean with your question but yes i have used localstorage, what i want to know is how i can make the log in system, i want it to log me in and redirect me to the other page if the username and password is correct and not if it is incorrect

Comment: What I mean is have you tried anything already? Do you have any jQuery code to handle the login?

Comment: nope not for the log in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store 2 arrays in Local Storage and push/pull from them:

Step 1: Make username/password arrays if they don't exist

```
if(localStorage['usernames'] && localStorage['passwords']) { // see if they exist yet
    // code to execute if the arrays already exist
} else {
    var usernames = []; 
    var passwords = []; // create two empty arrays if nothing is in Local Storage
}
```

Step 2: Create Sign up function

```
function signUp(signUpUsername, signUpPassword) {
    usernames.push(signUpUsername); // adds username to the end of array
    passwords.push(signUpPassword); //  "   password "   "   "  "    "
}
```

Step 3: Create Login function

```
function logIn(loginUsername, loginPassword) {
    var cu = localStorage['usernames']; // correct usernames
    var cp = localStorage['passwords']; // correct passwords
```

Go through array to see if credentials are correct

```
    for(var i = 0; i < cu.length; i++) {
        if(cu[i] == loginUsername && cp[i] == loginPassword) {
            // you have been logged in!
        } else {
            // incorrect credentials (display message!)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: this example ignores security and uses local storage, stored directly in the browser! Make sure the data isn't valuable, in case someone steals the data.**

Comment: On step 1, what would i want to do if the arrays do exist? =S

Comment: @random1234 You don't have to do anything. Maybe just `console.log('Arrays found!')` or something.